# After setting localstorage item, can't show it on screen

Tags: javascript, json

I basicly add my input values to `vals` array.

Then save the array to localStorage: `localStorage.setItem('mylist', JSON.stringify(vals));`

After that, i show values from `vals` array.

It saves the values to localStorage but  when i refresh, **values doesn't show up on screen with my dynamicly created li elements.**

Why?

*Note: I want to use localstorage with JSON.*

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r2n9a66z/)**

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var box = document.querySelector(".box");

var vals = [];
var li;
var list;

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;

  if (e.which == 13) {
    box.innerHTML = "";
    input.value = " ";

    // Push input value array
    vals.push(val);
    localStorage.setItem('mylist', JSON.stringify(vals));

    // Loop input values
    list = vals.map(function(item, index) {
      li = document.createElement("LI");
      box.appendChild(li);
      li.innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mylist'))[index];
    });
  }

}, false);

box.innerHTML = list;
```

Comment: Looks fine, what you expect?

Comment: Run fiddle again, you see undefined. I want to store from localstorage even page refresh. @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: That happen because you override the storage.

Comment: you have append `<li>` inside `addEventListener`, you need to use `var data = localStorage.getItem('mylist')` and then set/append `<li>` if *data* is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a page refresh the `list` array is empty. this will fix it:

```
var vals = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mylist')  || "[]");

vals.forEach(function(entry) {
    li = document.createElement("LI");
    box.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = entry;
})
```

The `|| "[]"` is a fallback in case `localStorage` returns null (the user never set a list)

You should also remove the last line of your script ( `box.innerHTML = list;` )

Answer (score 1):

Youd don't read anything from localStorage after page load. You read data from storage only in your `keyup` handler but you do it right after overriding it with new value. You have to get data from storage when page is loaded:
use this:

```
var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mylist'))
```

Comment: Yes i know it but i want to show it with li elements. They are just text now

Comment: To show them  as `li` elements you have to read data from storage first and then print your `li` based on this data

Answer (score 1):

It is saving in `localStorage` but in your code, after you refresh, you never populate the values in your HTML.

```
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var box = document.querySelector(".box");

var storageVals = localStorage.getItem('mylist');
var vals = storageVals ? JSON.parse(storageVals) : [];

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var val = e.target.value;

  if (e.which == 13) {
    box.innerHTML = "";
    input.value = " ";

    // Push input value array
    vals.push(val);
    localStorage.setItem('mylist', JSON.stringify(vals));

    renderList();
  }

}, false);

function renderList() {
  // Loop input values
  vals.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    box.appendChild(li);
    li.innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mylist'))[index];
  });
}

renderList();
```